# AttributeError: module 'tkinter.scrolledtext' has no attribute 'tkinter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, client, chat

I've been working on a python chat app for a school project, the general structure is that there's a client.py file and a server.py file. Forgive me if this seems basic, as I am just a beginner. Every time I try to fix one error, I run into another.

The code for client.py is as follows:

```
from operator import truediv
import socket
import threading 
import tkinter
import tkinter.scrolledtext
from tkinter import simpledialog

class client:

    def __init__(self):
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.connect(('localhost', 1234))

        msg = tkinter.Tk()
        msg.withdraw()

        self.nickname = simpledialog.askstring("Nickname", "Please choose a nickname", parent=msg)

        self.gui_done = False 
        self.running = True

        gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.gui_loop)
        receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)

        gui_thread.start()
        receive_thread.start()

    def gui_loop(self):
        self.win = tkinter.Tk()
        self.win.configure(bg="lightgray")
        
        self.chat_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Chat:", bg="lightgray")
        self.chat_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.chat_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.text_area = tkinter.scrolledtext.tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText
        self.text_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)
        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')

        self.msg_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Message:", bg="Lightgray")
        self.msg_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.msg_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.input_area = tkinter.Text(self.win, height=3)
        self.input_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.send_button = tkinter.Button(self.win, text="Send", command=self.write)
        self.send_button.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.end_button.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.gui_done = True

        self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.stop)

        self.win.mainloop()

    def write(self):
        message =f"{self.nickname}: {self.input_area.get('1.0', 'end')}"


    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.win.destroy()
        self.server.close()
        exit(0)

    def receive(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                message = self.sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if message == 'NICKNAME':
                    self.server.send(self.nickname.encode('utd-8'))
                else:
                    if self.gui_done:
                        self.text_area.config(state='normal')
                        self.text_area.insert('end', message)
                        self.text_area.yview('end')
                        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')
            except ConnectionAbortedError:
                break
            except:
                print("Error")
                self.server.close()
                break

    
Client = client()
Client()
```

First, I run server.py (which has its own errors I'll post separately), but then I run client.py and it displays the following errors in PowerShell:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 88, in <module>
    Client()
TypeError: 'client' object is not callable
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "client.py", line 36, in gui_loop
    self.text_area = tkinter.scrolledtext.tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText
AttributeError: module 'tkinter.scrolledtext' has no attribute 'tkinter'
```

How do I fix this?? I'm dying here :/

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't support multithreaded applications in the sense that only one thread can access it — trying to do this can lead to all kinds of strange errors occurring because it's not thread-safe.

Comment: `tkinter.scrolledtext.tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText` should be `tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must import scrolled text from tkinter

   ```
   from tkinter import scrolledtext
   ```
2. it seems you did a Ctrl+F replace that didn't work well (I did the exact same error on the exact same project as you)

> ```
> tkinter.scrolledtext.tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText
> ```

should be :

```
scrolledtext.ScrolledText
```

3. Remember to add the required parameters if needed, scrolledText is a tkinter frame object.

   ```
   self.text_area = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.win)
   ```